# Interval send file socket

Tags: javascript, socket.io, setinterval

I have a code ran bihourly and need to send the results via a socket. I've got it all set up and the first time goes fine. However the second time the function is called it no longer works. To demonstrate it I've hooked up my function to an interval:

```
var soc = require('socket.io-client');
var fs = require('fs');
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var calculationResultsFile = './publicdata/CalculationResults.json';

function sendFile(){
    var calculationResultsFile = './publicdata/CalculationResults.json';
    var socket = new soc('http://localhost:1234', {
        'reconnection': false,
        'reconnectionDelay': 1000,
        'reconnectionDelayMax': 10000,
        'reconnectionAttempts': 5
    });
    socket.on( 'connect', function() {
        console.log('Sockets connected');
        var stream = ss.createStream();
        ss(socket).emit('sendData', stream, {name: 'jsonHourly'});
        fs.createReadStream(calculationResultsFile).pipe(stream);

        socket.on('completedstreamfile', function(){
            console.log('File send. Closed socket.');
            socket.close();
        });
    });
}


setInterval(function(){
    console.log('Interval start');
    sendFile()
}, 10000);
```

Some output:

```
Interval start
Sockets connected
File send. Closed socket.
Interval start
Interval start
Interval start
```

I assume it is because the sendFile function doesn't close properly. However using return after socket.close() also doesn't do it.

EDIT: further clarification; The reason I need this is because the server might go offline or whatever. If I only establish the connection when the script is started it is not consistent.

Comment: Just curious why you're closing the socket each time? It partly defeats the purpose of websockets.

Comment: Thought about that too but even if I leave it open it is the same. Doesn't send after the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working. The problem was that this initiates the socket and all its event listeners multiple times. Additionally the 'forceNew' option should be true.

```
var soc = require('socket.io-client');
var fs = require('fs');
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var calculationResultsFile = './publicdata/CalculationResults.json';


var calculationResultsFile = './publicdata/CalculationResults.json';
var socket = new soc('http://localhost:1234', {
    'reconnection': false,
    'forceNew': true
});
socket.on( 'connect', function() {
    console.log('Sockets connected');
    var stream = ss.createStream();
    ss(socket).emit('sendData', stream, {name: 'jsonHourly'});
    fs.createReadStream(calculationResultsFile).pipe(stream);
});
socket.on('completedstreamfile', function(){
    console.log('File send. Closed socket.');
    socket.disconnect();
});
socket.on('connect_error', function(err){
    console.log('Connection error: '+err);
});
socket.on('connect_timeout', function(){
    console.log('Connection timeout')
});

setInterval(function(){
    console.log('Interval start');
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.connect();
}, 40000);
```

Shutting down the receiving server just gives an error and it will work once you start it up again. So all good.